# Understanding Car Servicing for a second hand car

Tags: service, servicing

I bought a peugeot 206 last year (a second hand one). Such car is my first car, I haven't owned one before, although I used to drive before such purchase. The car is quite old (I think 8-10 years), I never done a car servicing before, and I think I should do one to check that my car is still functioning well. I don't know if would make any difference do the car servicing in any mechanic, or a peugeot specific one.

What do they usually do when performing the servicing? Since the car is old would it make any difference in doing the servicing in a peugeot dealer or elsewhere?

Any general suggestion is appreciated.
(I'm in the UK if that could help)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always service a second hand car which is new to me so I knew the condition.  You don't need to use a specific Peugeot garage, you may find an independent garage cheaper and for servicing on an older car, anywhere should be able to do it.

The alternative is to buy a Haynes or similar manual, some basic tools and do it yourself.  You're best of doing this with a friend who is good on the tools to begin with and keep you right.

Comment: What's an heynes sorry? Is there some kind of list of suggested tools to own in order to do these simple things by myself?

Comment: Haynes is one of a number of companies that publish step by step manuals that show you exactly what you need to do to maintain your car.

Comment: Never heard of such manual before, I just had a look.

Comment: If not Haynes, then Chilton provides a similar service manual at a reasonable price.  You could purchase the factory service manuals from a dealer, but those manuals can be very expensive.  This is a great way to learn more about your car.  You can perform simple maintenance repairs yourself, and save lots of money!

Comment: What would you recommend then? It's definitely something I have to learn. I want to learn about my car. Which of such manuals do you think is the best?

Comment: Personally I've used Haynes and can recommend them.  I'd also suggest speaking to your local colleges and asking if there is a vehicle maintenance night class running at any time.  You will find many useful videos on youtube too.  Of course my final recommendation is this very site as it's packed full of useful information.

Comment: @SteveMatthews, hi. What kind of classes were you referring to? Could you forward me any link on the subject? It's just to understand what should I look for. Thanks

Comment: @user8469759 you'd have to check locally to yourself but local to me is this course; http://www.ncl-coll.ac.uk/courses/2677/vehicle-maintenance-evening-class  which is just one example of the kind of course I mean.

Comment: @SteveMatthews I think I've found something similar nearby, but I wasn't sure they were ok for DIY. Are these suitable for DIY in your opinion? Because basically that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user8469759 These are very much designed to allow you to maintain your own car.  They'll show you how to change the oil and filters.  How to assess and change brake pads. They'll also cover the regular checks you can make that will keep your vehicle in good shape and spot problems early.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking servicing means replacing consumable items after a specified interval (either miles, years or both) this can include things like engine oil, oil and fuel filters, brake fluid, spark plugs air filters etc.

The specific interval for a given item will be specified by the manufacturer and tends to cover things which are not expected to last the full life of the vehicle.

There are also things which should be replaced at specific points in the vehicle's life, notably the cam belt and associated ancillaries. Cam belts are especially important as while most consumables will gradually deteriorate a broken cam belt usually means a new engine.

There are also components which have variable wear rates such as tyres, brake pads etc which need to be inspected regularly and replaced as necessary.

Note that a service doesn't necessarily imply a full inspection of the vehicle and it is also a good idea to give it a reasonably regular inspection to look for any emerging problems such as corrosion, especially with reference to known problems with that particular model.

An MOT test will only check for road worthiness and won't flag up all maintenance issues, especially on non safety critical areas.